# Regex build from list behaves abnormally

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is my code:

```
import re

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.regex_list = ['omg', '\bwow']

    def print_regex(self):
        print('|'.join(self.regex_list))

e = Example()
e.print_regex()
```

Output:

```
omgwow
```

Expected Output:

```
omg|\bwow
```

So, I have a list of regexps that I want to join using OR operator. I do so expecting output to be OR joined string.

To my surprise it didn't join and it removed the \b too. This happens only inside the class while accessing self.

I tried directly joining outside of class which worked but I can't understand why this is not working. Could someone help me in understanding this?

EDIT:

```
regex_list = ['omg', r'\bwow']
print('|'.join(regex_list)) # Works outside the class
```

Comment: I understood that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` is backspace character which is causing your pipe to be removed (just like when you press backspace). You need to bypass backspace.

you can bypass it by replacing `\bwow` with `\\bwow`.

```
#output
omg|\bwow
```

Comment: I understand that, but why does it work when used directly rather than inside the class?  Please see my edit.

Comment: it doesn't work in that case either. Can you try running it again?

Comment: Oh cool. Got it, so \b is being treated as backspace somehow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It works using raw strings, prefixed with `r`, because those do treat backslashes as a literal character. See [the doc ](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for details.